# Prove there exists $x \neq 0$ such that $(I - M)x = 0$, where $(I - M)^{-1}$ does not exist.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that there exists a nonzero vector $x$ such that, provided $(I - M)$ is not invertible, we have $(I - M)x = 0$?

I'm not sure about how to go about this. I think that I'll need to use the fact that $(I - M)$ is not invertible, but I have no idea where.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't. If $I-M$ is invertible, it is bijective, hence as $(I-M)0=0$ there is no non-zero vector that gets mapped to 0 due to injectivity.

Comment: This is false : if $(I-M)$ is invertible, then multiplying $(I-M)x=0$ by $(I-M)^{-1}$ gives $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry - I know that $(I - M)$ is singular. So it is NOT invertible.

Comment: If $(I-M)$ is not invertible, then $ker(I-M)\neq {0}$. Try use this.

Comment: So since ker$(I - M) \neq 0$, there exists some $v$ such that $Mv = 0$? Is that right?

Comment: Since $ker(I-M)\neq \{0\}, there some $v$ such that $(I-M)v=0$, because $ker(I-M)$ is a subspace and cant be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $I-M$ is not invertible. Then, $I-M$ is not an injection (aka not 1-to-1) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1671496/167818)) and so there exists $u$ and $v$ with $u\neq v$ such that $(I-M)v = (I-M)u$. Thus $(I-M)(u-v) = 0$ and by assumption $u\neq v$ so $u-v\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M:\ell_{2}\rightarrow \ell_{2}$ be given by $Me_{i}=e_{i}-e_{i+1}$, where $e_{i}$ is the standard unit vector. Then $(I-M)$ is given by $(I-M)e_{i}=e_{i+1}$. Note that $(I-M)$ is not invertible as there is no $x\in\ell_{2}$ such that $(I-M)x=e_{1}$, but $(I-M)x\neq 0$ for all $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Note that this kind of construction only works in infinite dimensional space, for finite dimensional spaces you can follow the suggestions in the comments on your question.